# Map items gets replaced every time node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to implement cooldown to my command handler in my Discord bot, but I'm stuck.

The cooldown itself works, but when I try to use a command that is different from the one that I executed before, that cooldown gets replaced with the last one. Here's the code:

```
const cooldowns = new Map();

       try {
    
            const cooldown = cooldowns.get(interaction.user.id);
    
            if (cooldown && cooldowns.get("command") == command.data.name) {
    
                const remaining = ms(cooldown - Date.now(), {till: "second"});
    
                return interaction.reply({ content: `Please wait until cooldown expires! Remaining: ${codeLine(remaining)}`});
            }
    
            await command.execute(client, interaction, Discord, profileData);
    
            let startTime = Date.now() + command.cooldown;
            cooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, startTime);
            cooldowns.set("command", command.data.name); 
    
            setTimeout(async () => cooldowns.delete(interaction.user.id, "command"), command.cooldown);
        }
        catch (error) {
    
            console.log(`The interaction error is ${error}`);
    
            await interaction.reply({ content: "There was an error trying to execute this command. ", ephemeral: true});
        }
    }
```

So for example when I use the command `/hello`, with a cooldown of 30 seconds, the 1st time it gets executed, and if I try to execute it again the bot responds with the cooldown saying that I can't use the command until the cooldown expires, which is correct, but if I use another command, for example `/world` with 0 cooldown, the command gets executed correctly, but the cooldown for the `/hello` command gets canceled, and it can be used again.

I'm assuming that the `interaction.user.id` and the `"command"` items get replaced with new ones, and I can't find a method to create new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

According to your requirement, I created a data structure like below

```
{
   "userA": {
      "/hello": startTime
      "/world": startTime
   },
   "userB": {
      "/hello": startTime
      "/world": startTime
   }
}
```

`userA` is for user id

`/hello` and `/world` are commands

`startTime` is the cooldown for each command

You can check this implementation with some comments

```
const cooldowns = {}; //similar to Map but simpler

try {

  //cannot find any user in cooldowns map
  if (!cooldowns[interaction.user.id]) {
    cooldowns[interaction.user.id] = {} //create map to keep commands
  }

  //check if the cooldown exists in the commands
  const cooldown = cooldowns[interaction.user.id][command.data.name];

  if (cooldown) {

    const remaining = ms(cooldown - Date.now(), {
      till: "second"
    });

    if (remaining > 0) {
      return interaction.reply({
        content: `Please wait until cooldown expires! Remaining: ${codeLine(remaining)}`
      });
    }

  }

  await command.execute(client, interaction, Discord, profileData);

  let startTime = Date.now() + command.cooldown;

  cooldowns[interaction.user.id][command.data.name] = startTime

  setTimeout(async () => delete cooldowns[interaction.user.id][command.data.name], command.cooldown);
} catch (error) {

  console.log(`The interaction error is ${error}`);

  await interaction.reply({
    content: "There was an error trying to execute this command. ",
    ephemeral: true
  });
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

```
 if (cooldown && cooldowns.get("command") == command.data.name) {
    const remaining = ms(cooldown - Date.now(), {till: "second"});
    return interaction.reply({ content: `Please wait until cooldown expires! Remaining: ${codeLine(remaining)}`});
}
```

I think this part is causing the problem `cooldowns.get("command") == command.data.name`. If your new command matches with the previous command, you check the cooldown.

BUT whenever your new command does not match with the previous one, you bypass that condition which is the system won't check the remaining time.

The possible fix should be

```
 if (cooldown) {
    const remaining = ms(cooldown - Date.now(), {till: "second"});
    return interaction.reply({ content: `Please wait until cooldown expires! Remaining: ${codeLine(remaining)}`});
}
```

You only need to check the cooldown from the user id, and don't need to check command matching.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, because it would cooldown the user when using all the commands. If I were to use a command with a cooldown, I would't be able to use any other commands until that cooldown expires. :(

Comment: Ah now I understood your requirement, give me a while, I modify it again @SaverioScagnoli

Comment: Just one question before my modification, `but if I use another command, for example /world with 0 cooldown` which means the new command has no cooldown? once `/hello` get 0 in cooldown, what will happen with `/world`? @SaverioScagnoli

Comment: once `/hello` gets 0 in cooldown, or even if it has just been executed, or executed 10 seconds ago, I can still use all the other commands, but when I do so, the `cooldown.set`s will replace that user and that command in the map, sorry I know I'm bad at explaining XD, thanks for the help!

Comment: so `/world` will be executed immediately regardless of `/hello`? and how about other next commands? there are also executed without cooldown? @SaverioScagnoli

Comment: `/world` gets executed immediately after when I type it in the Discord chat, as it should. Same with all the other commands, even if they have cooldowns. The fact is that the new cooldown, even if it its 0 replaces the cooldown of the previous command

Comment: I updated the code for the sake of your requirement, please let me know if you don't understand any part of it @SaverioScagnoli

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help! I never used data structures before. The only thing I changed is the ms() function because `remaining` was being picked up as a string, like `"27 seconds"` so I just changed its location to the `if(remaing > 0)`. I was trying to figure it out from 2 days ago. Thanks!!